# High CPU Usage in Spring Boot Application with Redisson: MapCacheEvictionTask Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, cpu-usage, redisson

- I'm facing persistent high CPU usage in my Spring Boot application.
  The error when analysing heap dump: **instances of
  **"**org.redisson.eviction.MapCacheEvictionTask", loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @
  0x63d034430**"

  **Configuration Details:**

  - Redisson version: 1.7.11.RELEASE
  - Spring Boot version: 2.2.2.RELEASE

    ```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.11.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
    ```

  I have checked the Redisson and Spring Boot documentation for
  guidance and used the latest redis version as well which is 3.1.8

Comment: DItch that dependency and use `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` instead (without versions) so that you have a compatible and newer version. The Spring Boot version you are using is quite old and not supported anymore, I would suggest to upgrade at least 2.7.x.